# Finding all the eigenvalues of the blocked matrix with diagonal blocks

Tags: linear-algebra

#### Problem

> Find all the eigenvalues of the following matrix:
>
> $$
> M = \begin{bmatrix} 
> A & B \\
> C & D \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> where $A = diag\{a_1, \cdots, a_k\}$, $B = diag\{b_1, \cdots, b_k\}$, $C = diag\{c_1, \cdots, c_k\}$, $D = diag\{d_1, \cdots, d_k\}$, where $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i \in \mathbb{C} (i=1,\cdots,k)$.

---

#### Try

Since we have $AB = BA$, $CD = DC$, we have

$$
\mathrm{det} (M) = \mathrm{det} (AD - BC)
$$

and the characteristic polynomial is

$$
p_M(\lambda) = (a_1d_1 - \lambda)\cdots(a_kd_k - \lambda) - (b_1c_1 + \cdots b_kc_k) 
$$

however, I cannot proceed from here, since I am stuck at solving $p_M(\lambda) = 0$.

I have tried applying the fact : the eigenvalues of Kronecker product of matrices are the product of the eigenvalues of each matrix. But I think $M$ does not seem to be factored into a Kronecker product.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rearrange the rows and columns to bring $M$ into a more convenient form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the blocks commute, we have 
$$
\det(M - \lambda I) = \det[(A - \lambda I)(D - \lambda I) - BC]
\\ = \det \operatorname{diag}[(a_1-\lambda)(d_1 - \lambda) - b_1c_1, \dots, (a_n-\lambda)(d_n - \lambda) - b_nc_n]\\
= [(a_1-\lambda)(d_1 - \lambda) - b_1c_1] \cdots [(a_n-\lambda)(d_n - \lambda) - b_nc_n]\\
= \det \left[\pmatrix{a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1} - \lambda I\right] \cdots 
\det \left[\pmatrix{a_n&b_n\\c_n&d_n} - \lambda I\right]
$$
So, the eigenvalues of $M$ are the eigenvalues of the matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a_k&b_k\\c_k&d_k}$ for $k = 1, \dots, n$.

---

To reach the same conclusion, it also suffices to argue that there is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P$ such that 
$$
PMP^T = \pmatrix{a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1\\ &&\ddots\\&&&a_n&b_n\\ &&&c_n &d_n}
$$